# how to replace 2 new lines by one in the file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, ash

I have the following text file

```
config 'toto'
        option 
        option 

config 'titi'
        list 
        list 

config 'tutu'
        list 
        list
```

I want to replace each 2 new lines by only one when I display the file with `cat`.

I tried  the following commands but they didn't work

```
cat file | sed -e "s@$'\n'$'\n'@$'\n'@g"
cat file | sed -e "s@\n\n@\n@g"
```

the expected output is like this :

```
config 'toto'
        option 
        option 
config 'titi'
        list 
        list 
config 'tutu'
        list 
        list
```

Comment: Can you add what you expect the output to look like

Comment: @mikea : question update with expected output

Comment: Would it suffice to you `grep`ping out the empty lines?

Comment: `grep -v '^$' filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' file
```

**(OR)**

```
sed '/^[ ]*$/d' file
```

With `tr`:

```
tr -s '\n' < file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^$/d' foo.txt
config 'toto'
        option
        option
config 'titi'
        list
        list
config 'tutu'
        list
        list
```

If your empty lines contain whitespace you can use

```
$ sed '/^\s*$/d' foo.txt
```

or

```
$ sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' foo.txt
```

to filter them out as well.

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/^[[:space:]]*$/' foo.txt
```

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiny little `awk`:

```
awk 'NF' file
```

```
$ cat file
config 'toto'
        option 
        option 

config 'titi'
        list 
        list 

config 'tutu'
        list 
        list
```

```
$ awk 'NF' file
config 'toto'
        option 
        option 
config 'titi'
        list 
        list 
config 'tutu'
        list 
        list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -v '^ *$' YourFile
```

should be faster than sed

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Bash `while read` loop.

```
while IFS='' read line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then
        continue
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < file
```

Here, the loop will print every line that is not an empty string.